# files().update(…).execute() method returns “400 Bad Request”

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive SDK for Android, recently, I found `files().update()` method throw an exception "`400 Bad Request`" but it worked fine before, and `files().insert()` works fine, is Google Drive server's problem?

Comment: Please provide your code. When it returns 400, it means you forgot to pass some required parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Which version for Google Drive API you are using? Error might be because of the changes in files.update method in v2.

As mentioned here https://developers.google.com/drive/migration, Drive SDK v2 adds the non-backward compatible changes from v1 as parameter id has been renamed to fileId for files.update.